# Javafx Maven getting UnsupportedOperationException when trying to run my gui

Tags: java, maven, javafx, model-view-controller

So I'm working on a project for making a uml editor and I'm trying to get my gui to run but when I run `mvn clean javafx:run`
I get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Direc`your text`tMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:173)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:171)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
```

And this is my java MainWindow file

```
package com.classuml;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


// JavaFX Application Class
public class MainWindow extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/classuml/mainwindow.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    // Optional: You can add methods to this class to show the window from other classes.
}
```

And my fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Copyright (c) 2015, 2019, Gluon and/or its affiliates.
  All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

  This file is available and licensed under the following license:

  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
  are met:

  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation nor the names of its
    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
    from this software without specific prior written permission.

  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
  OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
  SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
-->

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.classuml.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Diagram" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Diagram…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Classes">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add class" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set relationship with..." />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete class" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Attributes">
              <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete Attribute" />
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Attribute" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show help document" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About UML Reader" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="275.0" layoutY="1.0" style="&#10;" text="UML Reader" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
            <ScrollBar layoutX="633.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="14.0" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

And when I run from the folder using the play button in the top in vscode I get this
`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

And I can't find too much information about why it is not working so this is the MainWindow.java

Please let me know if there is any information about this missing and I will be sure to make updates.

I have changing the `getResource("mainwindow.fxml")` instead but that did not work and I have tried doing a clean install on a vm linux machine and that did not work either.

Comment: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application` means that your JavaFX libraries are incorrectly configured (JavaFX cannot load the required native libraries for the platform).  Setup of JavaFX is provided in the [getting started instructions at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  Follow the instructions to get the minimal hello world application defined at openjfx.io running in your environment.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using x windows and the DISPLAY environment variable (or x windows in general) is not correctly configured.

Comment: [The `Java_com_sun_glass_ui_gtk_GtkApplication__1queryLibrary` method in the JavaFX native code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-glass/gtk/GlassApplication.cpp) is unable to determine a display when calling the GTK function [XOpenDisplay](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XOpenDisplay.3.html), with a null parameter.  In the documentation it notes: "if the display_name is NULL, it defaults to the value of the DISPLAY environment variable.", which is why I think your DISPLAY environment variable is not set appropriately.

Comment: Another option is using a JDK that comes bundled with the necessary *OpenJFX* libraries that implement *JavaFX*. At least two vendors provide such edgof their JDK products: Azul Systems & BellSoft.

Comment: You can also create a JDK that includes the JavaFX modules pretty easily using jlink (which is bundled as part of the standard JDK).